# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package Activity не видит ресурсы меню?

Tags: android, android-menu

[image: скриншот]

```
package com.example.node_just;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;




import com.example.node_just.R;
//import android.R;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private final static String FILENAME = "sample.txt"; // имя файла
    private EditText mEditText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     //   mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
      //action_open cannot be resolved or is not a field  ??
            case R.id.action_open: 
                openFile(FILENAME);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_save:
                saveFile(FILENAME);
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }



    // Метод для открытия файла
    private void openFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fileName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                inputStream.close();
                mEditText.setText(builder.toString());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    // Метод для сохранения файла
    private void saveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, 0);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            osw.write(mEditText.getText().toString());
            osw.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}



--------------------------- XML MENU--------------
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8g3sh2vL/1/

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.node_just' -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_open"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_day"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_open" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_save" />
</menu>
```

Comment: что за функция showAsAction ? Это ваша функция?

Comment: это пример отсюда : http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/texteditor.php

Comment: атрибут showAsAction, это режим показа элемента. Он может принимать значения:

never – не показывать элемент

ifRoom – показывать, если есть место

always – всегда показывать

Comment: да узнал спасибо. прочитайте ответ `metalurgus` он думаю правильно подсказал.

Comment: Убедитесь что у вас корректно подключена либа аппкомпата. Такое бывает если он не видит апкомпатовские ресурсы

Answer (score 1):

Замените `app:showAsAction` на `android:showAsAction`.
`showAsAction` - стандартный атрибут, который находится в схеме `android`

Comment: Для темы `AppCompat` с наследованием от `ActionBarActivity`/`AppCompatActivity` нужно указывать схему `res-auto`